# Meaning and function of ^ (caret) sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

In a web page, I see following script snippet.

```
(d.charCodeAt(i)^k.charCodeAt(i)).toString()
```

It was a part from a `for-loop`, and I know what `charCodeAt(i)` is, but I really wondered what is the functionality of `^` sign... I make some search but failed to find anything...

What is `^` and what function or operator exists in Python or other programming languages that do the same job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `bitwise XOR` operator. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> [Bitwise XOR] returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of
>   either but not both operands are ones.

Where the operands are whatever is on the left or right of the operator.

For example, if we have two bytes:

```
A 11001100
B 10101010
```

We end up with

```
Q 01100110
```

If a bit in A is set OR a bit in B is set, *but* NOT both, then the result is a `1`, otherwise it is `0`.

---

In the example you give, it will take the binary representation of the ASCII character code from `d.charCodeAt(i)` and `k.charCodeAt(i)` and XOR them. It does the same in Python, C++ and most other languages. It is not to be confused with the exponential operator in maths-related contexts; languages will provide a `pow()` function or similar. JavaScript for one has `Math.pow(base, exponent)`.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript it's the [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator - exclusive or. Only returns true if one or the other of the operands are true, but if they're both true or both false, it returns false.

In Python, it does [the same thing](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

Wikipedia's [XOR page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bitwise XOR. It performs an "exclusive or" in each bit of the operands.